Passing the model check but failed in compilation. How can I debug the issue?
I am a beginner in OpenModelica and currently focusing on thermo-hydraulic systems. As I am trying to build a district heating system, the model has passed the model checkout phase, yet failed in compilation with an error "no member named 'nominal' in 'struct INTEGER_ATTRIBUTE'".

I did some research and some indicate that it may be an internal bug. Hence I am trying to know whether this is due to my modelling, which I can work further to avoid it or indeed a bug that I should find a different way?
If the bug is related to my modelling, how can I debug it?
Many thanks for your help!

Hi Frank, are you sure you did not forget to input nominal values in some of your components?

I am sure. I built a much smaller model with all types of components that have been used in my larger model. The value inputs are similar. Interestingly, the smaller model works fine, but the larger model cannot pass compilation.

Hey Frank. Can you add some Modelica code to reproduce your issue? (See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
This looks like a bug in OpenModelica. Either your model isn't valid and OM should report an error or something during code generation is wrong. Please open an issue on our GitHub: https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/new?template=first_bug_report.md

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Apologies, I may have overlooked the warnings in the first place. In order to address those issues, I used command line "omc om_script.mos +d=aliasConflicts --maxSizeNonlinearTearing=50105 --maxSizeLinearTearing=5000" and it can indeed run the simulation. It may be because of the model has been relatively large or there are conflicts in alias. Anyways, I am putting my solutions here in case anyone else encounters similar issues.
